# active record, use instance variable was defined in before_destroy block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

**Some context:**

A company has many users. Whose one is the owner.
You can destroy everyone on the company except the owner.
Destroy the owner, it's like destroy the company. So you must do `company.destroy`
I prevent destroy user if he is owner, except if you are destroying the company.

**My code:**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy { @bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed = true ; p object_id }

  belongs_to  :owner,     class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many    :employees, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy

  def can_owner_be_destroyed?
    p @bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed
    p object_id
    !!@bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to        :company
  before_destroy    :cancel_if_owner

  def cancel_if_owner
    !self.is_owner? || self.company.can_owner_be_destroyed?
  end
end
```

**My question:**

When I call `company.destroy` I see my debug. I'm passing in `before_destroy { @bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed = true ; p object_id }` and I see my object_id.
When I passing in `can_owner_be_destroyed?` method, I have the same object_id, but my `@bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed` is `nil`. It's the only place on my code I touch the `@bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed` variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the order of declaration, your dependent objects can be destroyed before the `before_destroy` callback is run for the parent object.

You can test this yourself:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :owner,     class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many    :employees, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy

  before_destroy do
    @test_variable = "hi"
    puts @test_variable
    puts "Company destroyed"
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to        :company

  before_destroy do
    puts company.instance_variable_get(:@test_variable)
    puts "User destroyed"
  end
end
```

`"Company destroyed"` will be the last thing printed after all the `users` are already gone, and you will get an empty string `puts`ed in place of "hi" for each user, because `@test_variable` has not yet been set. However if you declare that callback before you declare the associations, `"Company destroyed"` will be printed first, and you should see `"hi"` printed as each `User` is `destroy`ed.

If you ask me, that's very unexpected. Callbacks can overcomplicate things and are often overused, how can we guarantee we know exactly what's happening in such a complex execution flow? Ruby has a built-in callback system for descendant objects that is much easier to understand, and very predictable in its behavior: `super`

```
class Company
  def destroy(*args, &block)
    @bool_allow_owner_be_destroyed = true
    super
  end
end
```

Anything you do before the call to `super` will be guaranteed to run before any of the dependent objects are destroyed or anything else that's triggered by `destroy`. There's no ambiguity when using `super`.

To cancel `destroy` for the `owner` you could also use `super`, along with an early `return`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  def destroy(*args, &block)
    return unless can_be_destroyed?
    super
  end

  def can_be_destroyed?
    !is_owner? || company.can_owner_be_destroyed?
  end
end
```

Overall I'd suggest that trying to carry state on an ActiveRecord object with an instance variable might get you in trouble at some point, especially if associated objects will rely on that state or you have multiple instances of your app running at the same time.

You could instead make this a db field and persist the change.

```
class AddAllowOwnerBeDestroyedColumnToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :allow_owner_be_destroyed, :boolean, default: false
  end
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to  :owner,     class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many    :employees, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy

  # You won't need this method b/c you now have `#allow_owner_be_destroyed?` for free
  # def can_owner_be_destroyed?
  #  p allow_owner_be_destroyed
  #  p object_id
  #  allow_owner_be_destroyed
  # end

  def destroy(*args, &block)
    update allow_owner_be_destroyed: true
    super
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  def destroy(*args, &block)
    return unless can_be_destroyed?
    super
  end

  def can_be_destroyed?
    !is_owner? || company.allow_owner_be_destroyed?
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for you very detailed answer.
but I'm not agree with you. You said "before_destroy callback is run for the parent object", but I think it depend the order of your declaration.
In your example you've changed the order of the declarations

Comment: I think the fact that the order of execution is not obvious to both of us is reason enough not to rely on callbacks for this, don't you? : ) Callbacks are powerful but can also be overcomplicated for things that can be achieved with built in language features. You also can't break out of an action like `destroy` from within a callback. I think using Ruby's built-in callback system (i.e. `super`) is a better fit for you. You can control exactly when it will be executed, and are able to return early out of your `destroy` method unlike with a callback. Ruby's powerful, it should be used!

Comment: I also still don't think you should rely on an instance variable at all to carry this state. I wouldn't assume I know when a new object will or won't be instantiated in a long execution flow like this, wiping out your instance variables. Might as well hit the database one extra time to guarantee the integrity of the object state

Comment: You're right about the order of declaration, sorry about that! I edited the answer. I still hold to the main point though, hope it helps.